# BehaviourSubject triggers "Expression has changed after it was checked" in Angular

Tags: angular

I am using Angular 11 and I use a `BehaviorSubject` to update the toolbar from completely different components. The toolbar subscribes to the `BehaviorSubject` as follows:

```
<breadcrumbs [crumbs]="messageService.getBreadcrumbs() | async"></breadcrumbs>
```

The `messageService` object is called from a child component and might update the toolbar at any point in time. But the error I get is:

```
core.js:6210 ERROR Error: NG0100: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked.
Previous value: ''. Current value: 'Project'.. Find more at https://angular.io/errors/NG0100
```

I understand the basic problem (as outlined in the link) but I am not sure how I can fix this with my BehaviorSubject. Any ideas?

Comment: One possible reason is your `BehaviorSubject` emits new values too rapidly.

Comment: I think it's throwing error beacuse of  function call in template

Comment: I see! I manually subscribe in my code and manually set a variable, wrapped inside a `setTimeout`, that seems to work now. Seems the `setTimeout(..., 0);` gets invokved right before the next render cycle and therefore passes

Comment: Have you tried debounce with getBreadcrumbs() observable?

Comment: Thx for sharing the idea. I haven't tried it, but introducing a timer in someway sounds like a hack workaround :-/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ChangeDetectorRef to detect the changes in your component. So, (inside the child component) you can basically do;

```
constructor(
 private cd: ChangeDetectorRef
){}

ngAfterContentChecked() {
  this.cd.detectChanges();
}
```

Comment: Could you ellaborate? After content is checked, I shall check for content changes again?

Comment: You basically say to Angular that after content is checked, there may be some changes that Angular could miss (becuase you use OnPush strategy), when Observable emits its values subsequently one after another, you should tell Angular to detect changes on every observable emission. I hope this is helpful.

Comment: Thanks so much for the explanation! That really helped a lot!